# How to make this cards in react-native?

Tags: react-native, expo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFJTd.png)

It needs to be spread out at 100 percent, so I need the card width to be in percent.

I have already tried, position and flex but It does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { View, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const win = Dimensions.get('window');
const { width, height } = Image.resolveAssetSource(require("../assets/image.png"));
const a = 0.5;

const App = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Image source={require("../assets/image.png")} style={styles.image}>
    </View>
  )

}

const styles = Stylesheet.create({
  image: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: a * win.width,
    height: (a * win.width)*(height/width),
  }
})
```

Here we are using the width of the screen to determine what should be the optimum width of the image. You can vary the value of `a` in order to set desired width %. `height` is calculated to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: This code does not work, I am a beginner and could not fix it.

Comment: @giorgi1998 I have edited the code. In place of "../assets/image.png", use your image's path.

Comment: TypeError: react_native_web_dist_exports_Image__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.resolveAssetSource is not a function

Comment: @giorgi1998 Are you using a remote image?